# CakePHP & Twitter Bootstrap Tooltips

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement tooltips for buttons from bootstrap-tooltip.js however I can not get them to work. I have imported the script along with jquery.js in my default.ctp file.

In an index file where I would like tooltips I have this button for which have tried to add a tooltip.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('<i class="icon-plus"></i>'), array('action' => 'add'), array('class'=>'btn', 'rel'=>'tooltip', 'data-placement'=>'top', 'title'=>'Add', 'escape'=>false));?>
```

I have working tooltips in a different HTML file that work like this;

```
<a id="x-tooltip" href="#" rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="x">x</a>
```

Have I missed something? Why won't this work in the php statement?

Comment: Is the working one too easy to read for you? Why change it?

Comment: You'd still need to init it, right? Something along the lines of `$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();` IIRC

Comment: Yeah I have <script type="text/javascript">$("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();</script> below the code.

Comment: @shakabra because the working one is html and the not-working one requires php.

Comment: Is it a .html file? If it is do you have your webserver setup to parse html files as php? Do you get html outputted or do you see your php code when you open your browser to that page. Check console for any js issues. Also, you should put that code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { // code here });`

Comment: @tigrang its a .ctp file. Everything is fine the button works as it should except I cannot get the tooltip to display on hover. I think its just a problem with my syntax, perhaps its not getting rel=tooltip assigned or something. I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: Did you import the css file too? Without the css file it won't work. jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/HPyq7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

You need to include bootstrap.min.js and jquery.js for it to work and also the bootstrap.css.

I made the button like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $albumList['AlbumList']['id']), array('class'=>'btn', 'rel'=>'tooltip', 'data-placement'=>'top', 'title'=>'View')); ?>
```

Last thing you need to do is to put this somwhere below your button.

```
        <script>
            $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip('toggle')
            $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');   
        </script>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Haha wow this is old, no longer working on this project but I did get this working. Thanks for the answer anyway :)